# Excel - SUMIF for multiple sheets, columns and rows

Tags: excel

Is there at faster way to sum cells from different sheet, columns and rows?
This is how I've solved it. But this example is from only six different cells. In my actual document there is a lot more.

```
=SUMIF(Optioiner!B3;Source!B5;Optioiner!N57)+SUMIF(Optioiner!B61;Source!B5;Optioiner!N116)+SUMIF('Äta lista'!B409;Source!B5;'Äta lista'!N470)+SUMIF('Äta lista'!B467;Source!B5;'Äta lista'!N529)
```

Comment: Why are you using SUMIF? All the range references are single cells. That works, but it's not what SUMIF was built for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, SUMIF seems to be overkill, since you only ever evaluate a single cell in each sheet.

Second, you could place a formula with a simple check in the same position on each sheet. For example on the Optioiner sheet

```
=if(Source!B5=N57,B3,0)+if(Source!B5=N116,B61,0)
```

Put that in cell Z1 or a similar cell that you can use on EACH sheet.

Then you can simply do a sum of all Z1 cells on all sheets

```
=sum('Optioiner:Äta lista'!z1)
```

This will create a sum of the values in cell Z1 in the sheets Optioiner and 'Äta lista' and all sheets that are between these two sheets.

Comment: if that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. if it didn't, leave a comment so I can follow up.